# videos or tutorials for vim haskell mode

Tags: haskell, vim, ide

I'm looking into a good ide to write my Haskell programs and I've opted for vim.
Now, I need a good tutorial to get started.

Do you know of any good tutorial ? or video ?

Comment: @AndrewMyers the link is broken.

Comment: Thanks.  I recommend Syntastic with [hdevtools](https://github.com/bitc/hdevtools).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a tutorial on how to use vim for haskell, but they are great videos that use haskell in vim. He does explain how he sets up his environment in episode 2.

[Episode one](http://youtu.be/ScS8Q32lMxA)

[Episode two](http://youtu.be/6KkF5-_erns)

Here's also a series I have been working on coding a Sed implementation using Haskell in vim.

[Playlist](http://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLUQzXLQ6jvHL_k3QOMKXehVoZdk-sKtHd)